# Rails STI has_many STI children of one type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-table-inheritance, sti

I've got a structure like so:

A holds one B (STI) which holds multiple C(STI)

How can I tell B1 (a sub class of B) that it holds multiple C1 (a subclass of C)
if that's even possible. (B1 can only contain C1, no other C subclass)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some actual code so that people willing to spend time on your question dont have to write everything from scratch and so that we don't have to make a bunch of assumptions about the implementation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution:

I need to specify the class_name in has_many like so

```
has_many :C, :foreign_key => :parent_id,  class_name: 'C::C1'
```

Comment: One gotcha with redefining the assocation in a subclass is that you will a `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError` if you have any assocations defined in the parent that go through it.

Comment: @max This is only an issue if the parent has an association to the STI parent class right?
As in if B had
    has_many :C, :foreign_key => :parent_id